# Angular 2 - Sweet alert call back function not working

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, angular2-services, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to delete an item in my angular cli app. I've used sweet alert as an alert and i want to delete an item from the list. Here is a code for that. This code is in typescript file.

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../../services/authentication.service';
declare var swal: any;
export class AdminUsersComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
    ) { }

    deleteUser(id) {
        let userData = {
           user_id: id
        };
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function(){
            this.authService.deleteUser(userData).subscribe(data => {
                // response
            });
        });

    }
}
```

Problem is when i confirm delete, it gives me error that "this.authserivce "is undefined. It is working properly if i don't use sweet alert as confirmation. I'm guessing i need to pass parameter in call back function but don't know what should i pass. So how i can solve this?

Comment: Can you send the entire code? What's `authService.deleteUser`

Comment: @manav i've updated code. take a look

Comment: maybe sweetalert is overwriting `this`?

Comment: Could you try a lambda function `() => {}` instead of `function(){}` to retain context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st solution:** Use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) because the function expression bind `this` with its own `this`

```
swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            this.authService.deleteUser(userData).subscribe(data => {
                // response
            });
        }
    });
```

**2nd solution:**

```
let that = this;
swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.value) {
            that.authService.deleteUser(userData).subscribe(data => {
                // response
            });
        }
    });
```